# Visual Studio 2013 missing Call Hierarchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I want to open the Call Hierarchy of a property or method using C#. [According to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859(v=vs.120).aspx) I should just right-click on a Property and call the operation. But I do not have it in my context-menu

[image: menu]

I also use the ReSharper plugin, not sure if that has anything to do with it.
What is going on?

Comment: Try running without any add-ons

Comment: Of course you don't have a method highlighted.

Comment: I highlighted a Property: `PartNumberList` And of course I also tried it with methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deactivate Resharper like this

```
Menu Tools --> Options --> Resharper: Suspend
```

then the Call Hierarchy is available in the context menu.